# Series RLC circuits

Tags: power-electronics, wireless, signal-processing, electromagnetic

Suppose a series RLC circuit has its resonance frequency f_r. If we apply AC current of frequency f_r to this series RLC circuit then circuit has maximum current as output.
My question is little bit hypothetical.
What will be the output of the series RLC circuit if we apply AC current of mixed frequency where one of its frequency is f_r? For simplicity we can assume AC current made up of two frequencies, (say f_r and f_s) where f_r != f_s.

PS: I am very sorry for any incovenience. Please comment if still there is ambiguity.

Comment: Please use latex to describe the equations, edit the question and reopen it. Thanks

Comment: Both alternating currents will flow as in any other type of circuit ranging from a short-circuit to a very high impedance. That's what currents do.

Comment: This has the makings of a good question, but you must clarufy question and answer comments.  ac sources in series or parallel?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, R, L, and C circuit components are *linear*, which means that if the circuit responds in a particular way due to one stimulus, and another way due to another, the response to a signal which is the sum of the stimuli will be the sum of the responses.

Put another way, in linear circuits where \$I\$ is a function of \$V\$, \$I(V_1(t) + V_2(t)) = I(V_1(t)) + I(V_2(t))\$.

To answer your question more directly, if you have a current \$I_1\$ due to signals of frequency \$f_1\$ and \$I_2\$ for signals of frequency \$f_2\$, then the resulting current from the sum of the two signals will be \$I_1 + I_2\$.

Things get more complicated when you consider high-frequency behaviour of circuit components, heating effects due to current, and other effects, but I think these are outside the scope of your question.

Comment: My question is theoretical. Please dont consider practical aspects. In theory what will be the output (in Ideal scenario)

Comment: @AbhilashKurmi Did you read my answer?

Comment: You mean to say that circuit will follow the homomorphism property. I am very sorry but I didnt get your answer, if possible can you please give more details.?

Comment: I(f_r + f_s) = I(f_r) + I(f_s) ? Please comment on this equation. I know the question is silly. But please tell me, what will be the output.

Comment: Continuation to previous comment..where I(x) is the fuction of series RLC circuit output as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In both instances, context makes it clear that you're describing an RLC circuit configured as an **RLC bandpass filter**, probably either like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#/media/File:RLC_series_band-pass.svg) or like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RLC_circuit#/media/File:RLC_parallel_band-pass.svg).

In the first case (one signal at a time), you note that the output is maximum when f_in = f_r (and, therefore, less than maximum for any signal f_s != f_r). This is totally reasonable.

In the second case (two signals at once), [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle) dictates that you'll just get out of the sum of what you'd get for the two signals individually (something that castle-bravo's answer also states).

In a third instance (infinite signals / signal+noise), which you didn't mention, the same thing happens. The signal at f_r makes it through, while everything else is more attenuated.

Understand that you're still describing a filter. **That's the net effect.** If signal f_r passes through attenuated slightly and signal f_s is attenuated a lot, **you end up with a filtered signal at frequency f_r**.

Of course, one pass through the filter won't eliminate all the other frequencies, but it will certainly help, especially if f_r and f_s aren't close and the Q factor of the RLC circuit is high.

Comment: Thank you for comment. But can you please tell me, they follows the Homomorphism property or not?

Comment: Please add little more detail, as I am a student of computer science. So I have less exposure of circuits. I really appreciate your valuable comment.